# Передача значения переменной из JS в PHP через метод POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

Пытаюсь передать значение переменной из JS в PHP файл методом POST, но значение остается пустым.
Код на JS:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
let example = 100 + 100;
$.ajax({
  url: "example.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    amount: example,
  },
});});
```

Код на PHP:

```
<?php $amount = $_POST['amount']?> <div><?php echo $amount?></div>
```

Если в $amount подставить любое значение вручную, то в DIV echo выводит корректно.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скорее всего ты не понимаешь как это всё работает и проверяешь эти переменные либо обновив страницу либо на другой странице. И нужно понять, что это так не работает.....

Comment: Если ты таким способом реально хочешь вывести данные на другой странице, то тебе надо в `example.php` написать другой код.... который сохранит где-то переданные значения, а потом на другой странице, например `hello.php` ты достанешь эти сохранённые данные

Comment: не, мне именно из файла с js надо достать значение переменной example в файл example.php

Comment: В консоли разработчика на вкладке Сеть какой ответ?

Comment: @Daniil *"мне именно из файла с js надо достать значение переменной example в файл example.php"* --- прочитай ещё раз мои комментарии........... ....давай я уточню. у тебя есть два файла в одном написан js, в другом php. Каждый из них открыт в разных вкладках браузерах...и ты в одной вкладке отправляешь данные, а в другой вкладке обновляешь страницу и не видишь результат....так?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если я вас правильно понял, то да. У меня есть некий js-файл, в котором высчитывается значение переменной example. Посредством ajax методом POST я пытаюсь это значение отправить в файл example.php и получить его там через конструкцию $amount=$_POST['amount'], но на выходе пустой результат. Заранее благодарю вас на потраченное на меня время

Comment: @Daniil я тебе написал во втором комментарии что нужно делать (и это ещё при условии что ты в js всё правильно сделал и там ошибок в консоли при запросе нет)..... сохранять на сервере можно множеством путей: в файл, в БД, в сессию, в куки.

Comment: @u_mulder на файл с JS? 200. Скрипт из файла в целом к странице подтягивается

Comment: На ajax-запрос, естественно.

Comment: @u_mulder прошу прощения, не было возможности добраться до компа ответить. Затупил. На запрос ответ 200, метод POST. Во вкладке "payload" вижу корректное значение переменной. При попытке вывести это значение через конструкцию <?php $amount = $_POST['amount']?> <div><?php echo $amount?></div> -- пустая строка... Если я $amount присвою вручную значение (например 150 + 150), то в div'е появится 300

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что вы ajax-запросом отравляете данные в файл example.php, этот файл обрабатывает полученные данные, отправляет в ответ результат, но ajax-запрос этот ответ никак не интерпретирует, а просто отбрасывает.

Вот изменённый ajax-запрос, который показывает полученный ответ:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "example.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    amount: example,
  },
  success: (data) => {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Вам нужно написать вместо alert() свою обработку полученного ответа.

Comment: Попробовал. И все равно при попытке вызвать значение $amount через var_dump($amount) выдает string(0) ""

Comment: что интересное, там дальше формируется объект, который по обработчику из вашего кода вылезает в алерт, и там уже я вижу, что он получил значение $amount...

Comment: Ну вот, теперь обрабатывайте этот объект и меняйте на странице то, что нужно. Ajax-запросы работают именно так.